# Tkinter create_image

Tags: python, tkinter, tkinter-canvas

I've been working to get a simple Tkinter canvas to display an image using create_image.  I've read many threads that say that you need to create a reference to the object outside any function or class, otherwise the image object will be garbage collected.  Unfortunately, I still cannot get this to work.  Below is my code as it stands.  Ignore all the colors - I use them to illustrate where the frames and canvas live on the window.

-Kirk

```
import Tkinter as tk
from PIL import Image
from PIL import ImageTk

imageList = []
image = Image.open('len_std.jpg')

#event handlers
def hit_sel_click():
    imageList = []
    test_image = ImageTk.PhotoImage(image)
    imageList.append(cnv_hits.create_image(0,0,
                 image=test_image))    

#start root
root = tk.Tk()
root.title('SimView')
root.resizable(width=False, height=False)

#target/control variables
hit_sel = tk.StringVar() #holds radio button with activity level

#build GUI
frm_hits = tk.Frame(root, height=800, width=200, bg='#FF0000')
frm_hits.grid(rowspan=3, sticky=tk.W+tk.N+tk.S+tk.E)

tk.Label(frm_hits, text='Activity:').grid()
tk.Radiobutton(frm_hits, text='Low', variable=hit_sel, value='Low',
               command=hit_sel_click).grid(sticky=tk.W)
tk.Radiobutton(frm_hits, text='Medium', variable=hit_sel, value='Medium',
                command=hit_sel_click).grid(sticky=tk.W)
tmp = tk.Radiobutton(frm_hits, text='High', variable=hit_sel,value='High',
                 command=hit_sel_click)
tmp.grid(sticky=tk.W)
tmp.select()

frm_hit_list = tk.Frame(frm_hits, bg='#002288')
frm_hit_list.grid(sticky=tk.W+tk.N+tk.E+tk.S)

scrl_hits = tk.Scrollbar(frm_hit_list, orient=tk.VERTICAL)
scrl_hits.grid(row=0, column=1, sticky=tk.N+tk.S)

cnv_hits = tk.Canvas(frm_hit_list, bg='#888800',width=200, height=200,
                     yscrollcommand=scrl_hits.set)
cnv_hits.grid(row=0, column=0, sticky=tk.W+tk.N+tk.E+tk.S)

scrl_hits.config(command=cnv_hits.yview)

root.mainloop()
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are using `test_image` to draw the image of `cnv_hits`. That is right, but you forgot that `test_image` is local to `hit_sel_click()` method; which thing means it is not available to your main program.

To resolve this, you have 2 choices:

- Either declare `test_image` as [**`global`**](https://docs.python.org/2/faq/programming.html#what-are-the-rules-for-local-and-global-variables-in-python) inside `hit_sel_click()`
- Or run `test_image = ImageTk.PhotoImage(image)` before you declare `hit_sel_click()`.

**Nota Bene:**

- For the first case, you will need to run `root = tk.Tk()` before `hit_sel_click()`.
- In case you choose the second option, you will need to run `root = tk.Tk()` before `test_image = ImageTk.PhotoImage(image)`

If you don't do this, your program will raise a [`RuntimeError`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/exceptions.html#exceptions.RuntimeError) exception.

Comment: Thanks!  I was creating a reference tot he wrong variable.  No more late night coding for me.  8^D